# Discord.js : How do you see what game a user is playing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hi I am trying to get the game people are playing on my gaming server for auto role assignment.
I've looked around for the solution but i'm not getting anywhere.
What am i doing wrong here?

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
print(newMember.user.displayName + " is playing " + newMember.presence.game);
});
```

Comment: What's not working? At face value the code you posted looks sufficient

Comment: The code prints "<user> is playing [object Object]" i've tried game.name but that returns undefined and so does game.game. I cant find any documentation on it either.

Comment: start with wrapping the object with JSON.stringify(game, null, 2) to make it readable. Then make sure the library calls the 'presenceUpdate' listeners on initialisation, otherwise you would only have the notifications for users that switch to that game after you started the node script and not before.

Comment: For documentation look here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Game
The Game object has the toString method defined so you'd expect it to work find in string concatenation like you're doing, but perhaps you're using an outdated version of discord.js?
As an aside, when game.name is undefined, can you confirm whether the user actually has a game listed in discord itself? Might just be handling users without a game poorly.

Comment: I just tried what Zeachco suggested and that game me the result (tested with pubg) {
  "name": "PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS",
  "type": 0,
  "url": null
} i'll look at the documentation you provided. Thanks

Comment: Thanks guy i found the solution, i get the presence.game and store it in a variable named game. Then running game.name = game.name.toString() and then printing game.name returns the game the user is playing. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution! You may want to consider answering your own question (yes, you can do that!) and accepting it; that way, that makes it more visible that this question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
var game = newMember.presence.game;
game.name = game.name.toString();
print("user is playing " + game.name);
```